# Browser is not opening when running Jenkins as a service

Tags: jenkins, selenium-webdriver

I am running my selenium tests in IE in a Windows VM with the help of Jenkins. When running java -jar jenkins.war, my suite is working fine..

But when Jenkins is running as a service, browser is not opening and always it is failing.

I have opened the service properties and given Allow service to interact with desktop.

The alternate way I am running java -jar jenkins.war as a start up.. But this is starting jenkins when I login VM but if some circumstances due to windows patch update if machine gets restarted this is not working until I login the VM which is not i want.

```
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.35.528161 (5b82f2d2aae0ca24b877009200ced9065a772e73), userDataDir=C:\Windows\TEMP\scoped_dir6052_18573}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=false, version=70.0.3538.102, platform=XP, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=false, acceptInsecureCerts=false, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, setWindowRect=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=}]
Session ID: e6ef32b1e294ce9644a5078d9b8bf8c4
Failed ***********
Started InternetExplorerDriver server (32-bit)
2.51.0.0
Listening on port 45007
Only local connections are allowed
org.openqa.selenium.UnhandledAlertException: Modal dialog present: 
Build info: version: '2.41.0', revision: '3192d8a', time: '2014-03-27 17:18:15'
System info: host: 'xx-xx-xx', ip: 'xx.xx.xxx.xxx', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_191'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
Capabilities [{browserAttachTimeout=0, enablePersistentHover=true, ie.forceCreateProcessApi=false, pageLoadStrategy=normal, ie.usePerProcessProxy=false, ignoreZoomSetting=false, handlesAlerts=true, version=11, platform=WINDOWS, nativeEvents=true, ie.ensureCleanSession=false, elementScrollBehavior=0, ie.browserCommandLineSwitches=, requireWindowFocus=false, browserName=internet explorer, initialBrowserUrl=http://localhost:45007/, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, ignoreProtectedModeSettings=false, enableElementCacheCleanup=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=dismiss}]
Session ID: dbbe2316-a3b3-4e39-82e3-04dae698ec73
Nov 16, 2018 6:17:43 PM org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions findElement
WARNING: WebDriverException thrown by findElement(By.id: txtUserName)
org.openqa.selenium.UnhandledAlertException: Modal dialog present: 
Build info: version: '2.41.0', revision: '3192d8a', time: '2014-03-27 17:18:15'
System info: host: 'xxx-xx-xx', ip: 'xx.xx.xxx.xxx', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_191'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
```

Comment: What errors do you see in jenkins console? Adding logs to your question will help others to better understand the problem

Comment: I am not seeing any error in the logs

Comment: It's strange.. if the browser fails to start it should print something in the console. Just to make sure we are on the same page, inside of every jenkins job there is a link to open a console that shows log of the process run by current job

Comment: I have attached exception logs.

Answer (score 0):

Error log states that your test failed because of:

```
org.openqa.selenium.UnhandledAlertException: Modal dialog present
```

It happens when some alert appeared and was not properly handled by your test. To fix it you need to add a logic to handle alert before you call a method to look for an element `findElement(By.id("txtUserName"))`. The code might look like this:

```
try {
    Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
    System.out.println("Alert appeared. Text= " + alert.getText());
    alert.accept();
} catch (NoAlertPresentException ignored) {
    //if alert is not present for some reason we don't want to fail and can continue a test 
}
```

or you can wrap to a findElement call with a try catch, then close the alert, and try your logic again:

```
WebElement el;
try {
    el = findElement(By.id("txtUserName"));
} catch (UnhandledAlertException f) {
    try {
        Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
        System.out.println("Alert appeared. Text= " + alert.getText());
        alert.accept();
        el = findElement(By.id("txtUserName"));
    } catch (NoAlertPresentException ignored) {
        //if alert is not present for some reason we don't want to fail and can continue a test 
    }
}
```

Comment: But the same code is working when run Jenkins in a command prompt

Comment: it's a bit hard to say without the details of alert, but the fact is that in your second case there is some alert that affect your test. if you add a system out print ln with an alert text you will most probably see what the problem is. Please share an alert text - it might help to resolve your issue.